# QT QTableWidget::item() returns nullptr even when widget assigned to it

Tags: c++, qt

This is driving me nuts. Here's the relevant code:

```
//Inside UI class
QTableWidget *table_view;
```

Later,

```
QLabel* lb_param_id = new QLabel(this);
lb_param_id->setText(QString::number(param_id));

QLabel* lb_param_name = new QLabel(this);
lb_param_name->setText(QString(param_name));

QLineEdit* te_value = new QLineEdit(this);
te_value->setText(QString(value));

QPushButton* pb_command = new QPushButton();
pb_command->setText("Change");

...

if(ui->table_view->rowCount() <= param_id)
    ui->table_view->setRowCount(param_id + 1);

ui->table_view->setCellWidget(param_id, 0, lb_param_id);
ui->table_view->setCellWidget(param_id, 1, lb_param_name);
ui->table_view->setCellWidget(param_id, 2, te_value);
ui->table_view->setCellWidget(param_id, 3, pb_command);

for(int i =0; i < ui->table_view->rowCount(); ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ui->table_view->columnCount(); ++j)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem* item = ui->table_view->item(i, j);

        //Here, item is nullptr. Why?
        item->setForeground(QColor::fromRgb(255,255,255));
    }
}
```

I set widgets, then try to change foreground of all widgets inside `QTableWidget`. However, what is returned from `ui->table_view->item()` is nullptr. What is going on here? btw, The column count is set at initialization.

Comment: What is the value of `param_id`?

Comment: `param_id` is 0. At least for now.

Comment: You want to get an item (`QTableWidgetItem`) from your table, but I don't see where you add items to it. `setCellWidget()` function does not add **items** to the table.

Comment: @vahancho : Ok, then how should I go about colorizing text here? Because whateverI do, I cant seem to get the table widget to be colored in the way I want.

Comment: @nakiya, add table items first, than assign cell widget to each and than try to color them as you did.

Comment: how is `table_view` constructed

Comment: Basic colorization can be done without widgets using `QTableWidgetItem::setBackground` and `QTableWidgetItem::setForeground`.

Answer (score 0):

Add following few lines of code.

```
if(ui->table_view->rowCount() <= param_id)
    ui->table_view->setRowCount(param_id + 1);

ui->table_view->setColumnCount(4);

ui->table_view->setItem(param_id, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
ui->table_view->setItem(param_id, 1, new QTableWidgetItem());
ui->table_view->setItem(param_id, 2, new QTableWidgetItem());
ui->table_view->setItem(param_id, 3, new QTableWidgetItem());

ui->table_view->setCellWidget(param_id, 0, lb_param_id);
...
```

Basically, you need to insert the data into the cell first before you can set widget. In your case, you don't have meaning fully data.

Inspecting the qt source, this is the how setCellWidget() imaplemented:

```
   void QTableWidget::setCellWidget(int row, int column, QWidget *widget)
   {
       QModelIndex index = model()->index(row, column, QModelIndex());
       QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget(index, widget);
   }
```

Without setting the cell first, the model index is invalid index. I agree qt should insert the data if returned index is invalid. For now, you have to work with qt code.